# Using parse for data sync and data fetch

Tags: php, ios, core-data, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

I'm writing an app which allows users to receive push notifications according to some logic, described below.

**Context:**

1) User selects a stock, and sets a price to be alerted at. E.g. Google, 500$.

2) **Data Sync step:** This information gets saved (in Core Data) AND transferred to a remote MySQL DB via PHP.

3) **Data Fetch step:** Pending TO DO: On server side (where the PHP script is located), setup a script which fetches the CURRENT market value for the stock (Google) and compare it with the value set by the user (500$).

4) Pending TO DO: According to business logic (i.e. if market value > user value etc.), send Push Notification to user.

**My question: Is it possible to do steps 2,3 and 4 in Parse?**

The idea is that multiple users would be selecting stocks and setting prices to be alerted at.

If these steps can be done in Parse, then I'd essentially user Parse as my 'server-side'.
Unfortunately having searched through documentation, I'm still not sure if it's possible.

Thanks!